# Deprecated: `config.adapters.default` Sails.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

When I lift my sails project I get these warnings on terminal

> debug: Deprecated:   `config.adapters.default` debug: (see
>   http://links.sailsjs.org/docs/config/connections) debug: For now, I'll
>   pretend you set `config.models.connection`.
>
> debug: Deprecated:   `config.adapters` debug: (see
>   http://links.sailsjs.org/docs/config/connections) debug: For now, I'll
>   pretend you set `config.connections`.
>
> debug: Deprecated:   `config.adapters.*.module` debug: (see
>   http://links.sailsjs.org/docs/config/connections) debug: For now, I'll
>   pretend you set `config.connections["disk"].adapter`.

And my data is not stored in mysql DB.
This is my api model code

```
module.exports = {

  schema:true,

  tableName: 'BusStop',

  adapters: 'mysql-adapter',

  migrate: 'safe',

  attributes: {
    stopID:{
        type: 'int'
    },
    stopName:{
        type: 'string'
    },
    latitude:{
        type: 'float'
    },
    longitude:{
        type: 'float'
    }
  }
};
```

This is my local.js code

```
module.exports = {

   port: process.env.PORT || 1337,

    environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',

    adapters:{
      'default': 'disk',
      disk:{
        module:'sails-disk'
      },

      'mysql-adapter': {
        module    : 'mysql-sails',
        host      : '127.0.0.1',
        user      : 'root',
        password  : '',
        database  : 'PublicTransport',
        schema    : true
      }
    }

};
```

And this is my connections.js code

```
module.exports.connections = {
 localDiskDb: {
    adapter: 'sails-disk'
  },
  'mysql-adapter': {
    module    : 'sials-mysql',
    host      : '127.0.0.1',
    port      : 3306,
    user      : 'root',
    password  : '',
    database  : 'PublicTransport'
  },
  someMongodbServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
  },
  somePostgresqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
    host: 'YOUR_POSTGRES_SERVER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS',
    user: 'YOUR_POSTGRES_USER',
    password: 'YOUR_POSTGRES_PASSWORD',
    database: 'YOUR_POSTGRES_DB'
  }

};
```

I want to know how can I remove these Deprecated warnings and why my data is not being stored in the Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the links in those deprecation warnings are incorrect.  For information on how to configure Sails connections, see http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.connections.html.

You should be able to make those messages go away by following their instructions regarding what config keys to set.

In order to set a connection for a specific model, you now set the `connection` property:

```
module.exports = {

  schema:true,

  tableName: 'BusStop',

  connection: 'mysql-adapter', // "adapter" is now "connection

  migrate: 'safe',

  attributes: {...}

}
```

In order to specify the adapter to use for a connection, use the `adapter` key, not `module`; you're already doing this in most of your connections, you just need to update `mysql-adapter`.

In your **config/local.js** you're using the deprecated `adapters` key to set up connections; use `connections` instead.

Lastly, in order to set a default connection for all of your models, you do as the deprecation message says and set `sails.config.models.connection` rather than `sails.config.adapters.default`; you can do so easily in the **config/models.js** file, or in your **config/local.js** like so:

```
module.exports = {

  models: {
    connection: 'mysql-adapter'
  },

  ...more config...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It removed the deprecation warning successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This warning can also be generated if your project has an **config/adapters.js** file. If the file is empty it can be deleted and Zap the warning is gone.If it contains code then you will need to migrate it to the correct path **config/models.js** and **config/connections.js**